# place spirtes on top of background sprites

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I have a loop in javascript which creates tiles for a board game. I need to be able to place sprites on tiles, in two different ways. I need the option to place sprites on a specific tile and or auto generate position of sprites on the tiles. I'm not sure how to start this process because each tile is generated by a loop and not given a unique variable

```
for (i=0; i<64; i++){
        var tile = cc.Sprite.create(res.Tile_png);
        this.addChild(tile,0);
        x = centerpos.x + ((i % 8) - 3.5) * tile.getBoundingBox().width;
        y = centerpos.y + (Math.floor(i / 8) - 3.5) * tile.getBoundingBox().height;
        tile.setPosition(x,y);
    }
```

Comment: [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) are useful for storing arrays of related objects